# Проблема с Samsung`ами

Tags: java, android, samsung

Проблема такая, есть мой фрагмент открывается он из другого фрагмента, но при попытке запустить этот фрагмент на телефонах(Планшетах) Samsung приложение перестает отвечать, на корпоративном же планшете выдает ошибку

```
Writing exception to parcel
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14525)
                                                at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2258)
                                                at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:663)
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
                                                at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Есть ли у кого идеи, в чем может быть суть проблемы?

```
    11-02 11:16:31.558 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.568 2702-3011/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3594
11-02 11:16:31.578 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.593 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.608 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.628 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.643 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.658 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.678 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.693 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.708 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.728 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.733 2702-22332/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
11-02 11:16:31.743 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.758 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:31.993 2702-3120/? E/WifiService: Start scan, start assoc
11-02 11:16:32.028 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.043 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.058 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.063 2230-2495/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
11-02 11:16:32.078 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.093 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.108 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.128 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.143 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.148 2702-3054/? E/Tethering: No numeric data
11-02 11:16:32.158 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.178 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.193 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.208 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.228 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.243 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.258 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.278 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.293 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.308 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.328 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.343 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.363 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.378 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.393 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.493 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.508 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.528 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.543 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.558 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.578 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.593 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.608 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.628 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.643 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.658 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.678 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.693 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.713 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.728 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.743 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.763 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.793 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.813 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.828 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.843 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.863 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.878 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.893 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.908 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.928 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.943 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.963 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.978 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:32.993 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.013 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.028 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.043 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.063 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.083 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.093 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.108 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.128 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.143 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
11-02 11:16:33.158 2239-2239/? E/display: invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
```

Comment: так вроде там черным по серому написано - нужен пермишн "INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL", который видимо нужно в манифест прописать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас планшет на 6 андроиде, Самсунг не причем. На 6 андроиде runtime permission. Вам нужно спрашивать эти разрешения у пользователя когда вы пытаетесь дернуть метод, которому нужно это разрешение. Почитайте вот это https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/. И советую использовать эту либу https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте перпищен в манифест вместе с `android:protectionLevel="signature"`.

Более подробно [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html), как-то так:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Comment: Пермишен уже есть, увы